# how to invalidate session in spring mvc for implementing logout functionality

Tags: java, spring-mvc, session

I have spring MVC application and i have implemented signout functionality but it's not working. When user is login, i am maintaining the user login details as a bean "UserDTO" inside the session by setting the attribute and when the user click on sign out hyperlink then inside the sign out function i am doing session invalidate by getting the session using request scope.here is the code.

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/SignOut",method = RequestMethod.GET) 
    public String signOut(HttpServletRequest request){
           HttpSession session=request.getSession(); 
 System.out.println("session id before invalidating it:"+session.getId());
          UserDTO userDTO=(UserDTO)session.getAttribute("UserDTO");
          System.out.println("userDTO obje"+userDTO.getFirst_name());
          session.removeAttribute("UserDTO");   
    session.invalidate(); 
System.out.println("session id after invalidating session is:"+session.getId()); 
}
```

I am getting same session id aftere invalidating the session 
**session id before invalidating it:8E8AE156B9AE963C9C2E9BCB0B9B13DB
session id after invalidating session is:8E8AE156B9AE963C9C2E9BCB0B9B13DB**

```
Feb 09, 2016 1:02:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'userDTO' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:179)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:143)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:127)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:421)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:142)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.indexNew_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(indexNew_jsp.java:346)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.indexNew_jsp._jspService(indexNew_jsp.java:197)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:684)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:471)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:329)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Does the code compile? public String signOut method does not seem to return a string.

Comment: Yes,i didn't added the return statement to the above code.its working fine

Answer (score 7):

You may try to use another controller for signout purposes:

```
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping("/SignOut")
    public class SignOutController {

      @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
      public String logout(HttpSession session) {
        session.invalidate();
        return "redirect:/home";
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on downsides of this approach?

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the UserDTO object in the session. comment it and check if it invalidates.

Comment: can you post the exact printstack with the result of system.out.println statements